# Header banner link is forwarding to dev. subdomain, how do I change this?

Tags: header-image

bear with me I'm very new with wordpress and have just been thrown into something where I'm a bit over my head.

We have a site built with fusion builder using the Avada theme. Our headers use a banner image with a link that's supposed to link back to our home page (https://cohhio.org/), but instead links back to the dev subdomain for our homepage (http://dev.cohhio.org/), but for the life of me I can't find how to change this link.

Example page with this issue: https://cohhio.org/boscoc/gov-pol/

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

1. Either change it manually where it's defined, Fusion Builder, theme options or the customizer
2. Or carefully use a database search and replace plugin on the URLs

Comment: Well, that's pretty much the problem. I can't find where its defined, it doesn't seem to appear in the fusion builder, theme options, or customizer.

And I don't have direct access to the database.

Comment: Plugin "Better Search & Replace"